# Clang can't compile programs using the <functional> header anymore

Tags: c++, stl, clang, c++17

I'm using `clang` Version 4.0.0 on my system running ArchLinux, it always worked fine, but recently I can't compile programs that use certain STL headers anymore!

**Details:**

Output of `clang --version`:

```
 clang version 4.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_400/final)
 Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
 Thread model: posix
 InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Output of `gcc --version`:

```
 gcc (GCC) 7.1.1 20170528
```

**Example:**

I tried compiling the following trivial program:

```
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I am using the following command:

`clang++ -std=c++1z test.cxx`

And the result is failure:

```
In file included from test.cxx:3:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/functional:60:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/unordered_map:47:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/bits/hashtable.h:37:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/bits/node_handle.h:39:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/optional:1032:27: error: use of
      class template 'optional' requires template arguments
  template <typename _Tp> optional(_Tp) -> optional<_Tp>;
                          ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/optional:451:11: note: template
      is declared here
    class optional
          ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/optional:1032:40: error: 
      expected ';' at end of declaration
  template <typename _Tp> optional(_Tp) -> optional<_Tp>;
                                       ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/optional:1032:41: error: cannot
      use arrow operator on a type
  template <typename _Tp> optional(_Tp) -> optional<_Tp>;
                                        ^
3 errors generated.
```

Is this a bug in the STL or is my setup messed up?

Comment: have you tried rearranging the order of includes? This is what sometimes caused programs for me. Or try if removìng `#include <iostream>` and `#include <type_traits>` helps or leads to a different error

Comment: You seem to be using the gcc c++ standard library. Maybe try using the clang one. Something like `-stdlib=libc++`.

Comment: @ThFl I removed all other headers other than `<functional>` and the problem remains. I will edit the original Question. Thanks though.

Comment: @nshct Could you add the output of `clang --version` and `gcc --version` to your question (for future readers mainly)?

Comment: @Holt yes, I have added it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your setup is messed up. Funny enough, I have the exact same problem.

When you upgraded to gcc 7.1.1, libstdc++ (which is gcc's Standard Library) was updated alongside of it to provide the new features from C++17. Using gcc, this works, because it has almost full C++17 support.

But clang doesn't. A hint is the `-std=c++1z` flag instead of gcc's `-std=c++17` flag. Clang is missing [deduction guides](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction), and when it encounters them in libstdc++, it doesn't know what to do with them.

You can install the old libstdc++ package from the ALA, or you can download/use LLVM's Standard Library [libc++](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libc%2B%2B/), which naturally has only partial C++17 features.

Comment: You have just solved a major headache I've been having all day. Clang and clang-tidy were both choking on `std::thread{&Foo::bar, this}`. Turns out it was failing on the class template deduction. I could kiss you right now.