# std::variant implementation bug (Clang 4.0.1)

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, std, c++17

Here's my basic test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::variant<int> v{5};
    std::cout << std::get<0>(v) << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile it using Clang as follow: `clang++ -std=c++1z -g Sources/main.cpp`
I'm getting these errors:

```
In file included from Sources/main.cpp:2:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/variant:235:46: error: cannot cast 'std::variant<int>' to its private base class
      'std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_storage<true, int>'
      return __get(std::in_place_index<_Np>, std::forward<_Variant>(__v)._M_u);
                                             ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/variant:1192:35: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__detail::__variant::__get<0, std::variant<int> &>' requested here
      return __detail::__variant::__get<_Np>(__v);
                                  ^
Sources/main.cpp:6:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::get<0, int>' requested here
        std::cout << std::get<0>(v) << std::endl;
                          ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/variant:878:7: note: constrained by private inheritance here
    : private __detail::__variant::_Variant_base<_Types...>,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/variant:235:74: error: '_M_u' is a private member of
      'std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_storage<true, int>'
      return __get(std::in_place_index<_Np>, std::forward<_Variant>(__v)._M_u);
                                                                         ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/variant:878:7: note: constrained by private inheritance here
    : private __detail::__variant::_Variant_base<_Types...>,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/variant:377:34: note: member is declared here
      _Variadic_union<_Types...> _M_u;
```

But when I compile with GCC, with the same options, I haven't any errors, and I get the right output (`5`).

So I would like to know if it is really an implementation bug or if it comes from me.

Comment: What is the question ? here is not the bug report section of clang.

Comment: Please put all the errors into the question.

Comment: Switch to `libc++` - `clang++ -std=c++1z -stdlib=libc++`.

Comment: Question edited. I don't have libc++ so I will have to install it

Comment: @Ardakaniz See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584289/clang-cant-compile-programs-using-the-functional-header-anymore for more information,

Comment: Yep, that's all right, it works now, ty!